# How can I provide a function with composition API?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Is it possible to provide a function in Vue 3 and then call the function in the child component?

I know that this worked with the `option API`:

```
provide() {
    return {
        $list: this,
    };
},
```

But how can I achieve the same with the `composition API`?

**Here is my approach:**

**Parent component:**

```
setup(props) {
    const handleEdit = (item) => {
       emit("edit", item);
    };

    provide("$list", handleEdit);
    
    return { handleEdit };
}
```

**Child component:**

```
setup(props) {
    const { item } = props;
    const list = inject("$list");
        
    const handleEditItem = (e) => {
        list.handleEdit(item);
    };
}
```

**And here the error**
`Uncaught TypeError: _ctx.handleEditItem is not a function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it by passing an object, that way you can pass other variables and methods if needed.

**parent.vue**

```js
setup(props) {
    const handleEdit = (item) => {
       emit("edit", item);
    };

    provide("$list", {handleEdit}); // <= change here
    
    return { handleEdit };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
setup(props) {
    const { item } = props;
    const list = inject("$list");
        
    const handleEditItem = (e) => {
        list(item);
    };

    return { handleEditItem } 
}
```

1. in your Vue 2 example, you are providing whole component (`this`)
2. In Vue 3 code, you are providing just the `handleEdit` function so what you get when you call `inject` is again just a function
3. You forget to return `handleEditItem` from Child `setup` - thats why you got error `_ctx.handleEditItem is not a function`

Comment: Thank you! But that also not worked.
Do you now how to provide the whole component with the composition API?
Because ```this``` is no longer available.

Comment: You just can't provide whole component using Composition API. And I dont think it is a good idea anyway

Comment: This would work too. Maybe he meant to return `list` as the handler rather than recreating `handleEditItem` in the child. (Assuming that's what he's trying to do.  It's unclear.)

Comment: The code is from OP ....I was trying to make just minimal changes required to make it work. And fail to notice the OP forget to return `handleEditItem` from setup. Fixed now.